# WKWebView: The form is not submitting in WKWebView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, form-submit, wkwebviewconfiguration

I am using a **WKWebView** and when the form is submitted, I am getting the breakpoint in **decidePolicyFor navigationAction** delegate method and the following condition is also true.

> navigationAction.navigationType == .formSubmitted

The following code is also printing the expected data -

> print(String(data: (navigationAction.request.httpBody!), encoding:
> .utf8))
> print(navigationAction.request.mainDocumentURL)

Can anyone please help me with the issue?
**Xcode Version: 12
iOS Version: 14**

Do I have to configure something or allow some policies to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Does you JavaScript have `window.open()`? If so, you will need to handle it yourself. Implement WKWebView's `UIDelegate` and handle the action in the following method:

```
optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
    createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, 
                  for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, 
       windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView?
```

In this method, you can create a new WKWebView with the configuration obtained and present it on the screen.

Comment: It doesn't have window.open(). There is one small HTML form and there is the following script to submit the form. <script>window.onload = function(){  document.forms['myForm'].submit();}</script>